# XYZ to LLA returns latitude in range -180 - 180 instead of -90 - 90

Tags: android, geocoding

I'm working on 3D globe for Country picking. It is represented by a sphere with radius equals to 1. When user tap a screen i'm getting a point using ray object picking technique and then I'm trying to conwert it to lat, long nex way:

```
double alt = 1;
double lat = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
double lon = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos(z/alt));
```

This code returns latitude in range -180 - 180 degrees but google geocoder says that it should be in range -90 - 90 degrees.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `atan2` for longitude and `asin` for latitude.

```
double alt = Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y+z*z);
double lon = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(y, x));
double lat = Math.toDegrees(Math.asin(z/alt));
```